# Force UITypeEditor to display a initial value for a Enum type

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, enums, propertygrid

I have a class with name `EnumFlagsEditor` that inherits from [UITypeEditor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor?view=netframework-4.8) in order to design a type editor capable to edit a Enum with [FlagsAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=netframework-4.8), by using a custom [CheckedListBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox?view=netframework-4.8), and also to be able edit a normal Enum too within the same custom editor.

In the overriden [UITypeEditor.GetEditStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor.geteditstyle?view=netframework-4.8) method, I verify whether or not the source Enum has the `FlagsAttribute` set. If the Enum type has this attribute class, then I return `UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown` to diplay my custom `CheckedListBox`. If does not have it, I return `UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal` and .NET Framework does the rest using the default editor to edit Enums using a default `ComboBox` to display and select the Enum values/names.

The problem is, the default built-in editor in .NET framework class library to edit a normal Enum, I noticed it searchs for a Enum name with value 0 to display it as default, and If it does not found it, throws a `System.ArgumentException` and does not display a default value.

Take as example this Enum:

```
public enum TestEnum {
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 4
}
```

That will throw a `System.ArgumentException` in the editor of a property grid and will not display a default value, because default .NET Framework editor for a Enum expects a value of 0 inside the Enum...

[image]

Now, using the [System.DayOfWeek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek?view=netframework-4.8) Enum to see the difference:

[image]

`DayOfWeek.Sunday` (0) is selected by default so any exception is thrown.

Then, in my `EnumFlagsEditor` class I would like to prevent this behavior. I want the editor to show a default value in the property grid for my editor. I don't care about the exception, but I would like to display a specific, initial value... to be more exact, the smallest defined value in the source Enum.

How can I do this?.

Comment: This problem got started with an object that was not constructed correctly.  It has a property with an illegal value.  It ought not be the editor's job to fix that bug, after all the user doesn't *have* to edit the property.  A [Flags] enum declaration should have a None=0 member so its default value is always legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a UITypeEditor issue, but a [TypeConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?view=netframework-4.8) issue. What you can do is derive from the standard [EnumConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.enumconverter?view=netframework-4.8) class, like this:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(MyEnumConverter))]
public enum TestEnum
{
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 4
}

public class MyEnumConverter : EnumConverter
{
    public MyEnumConverter(Type type)
        : base(type)
    {
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        try
        {
            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }
        catch
        {
            if (destinationType == typeof(string))
            {
                // or whatever you see fit
                return "a";
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

PS: you can avoid the exception catch and do your own conversion, but it may be more difficult than it looks in the general case (depends on enum underlying type, etc.).